# "scanf" function making my whole program crash?

Tags: c, crash, scanf

I decided to write as my first C program a slot-machine. However, I have ran into some difficulties.

```
scanf("%d", decision);
if (decision == 1)
```

It seems that whenever this part is used, the whole program crashes. Why?

EDIT: Answered. I had forgotten to include an ampersand before the "decision". Thanks everyone!

Comment: @chevybow This question is both too broad and off-topic here. The suggestion to start with a simpler task and go through a book is a constructive suggestion.

Comment: One obvious mistake: you have to use "==" for equality checks, not "="

Comment: To insert code, copy and paste the code into the body of your question, highlight it, and press the button with the curly-braces.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Ctrl-K is usually the shortcut key.

Comment: And use `scanf("%d", &decision);`, maybe the missing & was the reason for your crashes

Comment: If your problems are solved for now, you might consider to delete this question, since it will probably not be useful for future readers

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from a simple error: you forgot the `&` to pass the address of `decision` instead of its value:

```
scanf("%d", &decision);
```

Note that this kind of error can be avoided by increasing the warning level of the compiler: `gcc -Wall`, `clang -Weverything` or `cl /W4`

Note also that you should check the return value of `scanf()`. It should return `1` if the number was correctly converted into `decision`. Otherwise using `decision` may have undefined behavior.